# No desktop environment after failed upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04

Tags: 22.04, support

I was using Ubuntu 21.10 and I got a notification message to upgrade to 22.04. I performed the upgrade, but during the upgrade I got an error: "Oh no something gone wrong [*sic*]". I used <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> and was able to finish the distro-upgrade. I rebooted the computer but it only loaded a terminal. It doesn't launch the GUI.

What can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: I upgraded 20.04 to 22.04 LTS. After rebooting and seeing that everything looked okay, I continued normal usage. After some time, I had a sudden black screen. Subsequent reboots landed me at the terminal. This was the solution.

Comment: I did an upgrade from a, now out of support, 21.10; and this also solved the issue.