# Ubuntu 22.04 boots to a black screen with login

Tags: boot, login, 22.04, recovery-mode

When I try to boot my machine, this is the output:

```
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS <my_name>-pc tty1
<my_name>-pc login:
```

The whole screen is black. If I login in then it's like I'm in a huge terminal because I can run command in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Do you have the correct driver for the GPU installed? Did it work correctly before and it stopped or has it never worked?

Comment: All of a sudden if freezed and while rebooting it went like this. Before the freeze it was working properly.

Comment: Update: I tried to `sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop` and the package was not found. Could this be the problem?

Comment: The "Duplicated" question is many years old and has more questionable answers than we can expect the OP to try, (52 answers). I vote to keep this question open. All answers that use WUBI as a solution should be eliminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question.

To anyone that is having the same problem as me, and is not really technical (like me), here's what solved it for me.

What I was seeing was tty (“teletypewriter”), which is a text-only terminal commonly used as a way to get access to the computer to fix things. I was put into this "environment" because I somehow (after an update) managed to uninstall my desktop.

My advice is:

1. Log in into tty with your username and password.
2. Check if you have the `ubuntu-desktop` package installed. I did this by typing `sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop`, which returned something like `package not found`.
3. If you find out that the package is missing, run `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. After the installation, my desktop opened automatically and everything was fine.

Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: It says ``` package Ubuntu desktop is not available! But is referred to by another package ``` package Ubuntu-desktop has to installation candidate

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo, I had the same issue. After running an `update` and `dist-upgrade`, I suddenly got thrown into terminal mode. A reboot also lead to terminal mode. I checked the update log (/var/log/apt/history.log) and the `dist-upgrade` indeed removed `ubuntu-desktop`; I am stil baffled why. Installing `ubuntu-desktop` again solved the problem.

Comment: Similar issue and solution at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405812/no-desktop-environment-after-failed-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04